# Can not get manually generate id with localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a `data` object of form-field data where `id` key has empty string as the initial value. I am trying to generate ids for every submitted form data and save in browser's storage. That, `data.id = generateEmployeeId();` is written below:

```js
function generateEmployeeId() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId === null)) {
        localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, '0');
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line radix
    let id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId));
    localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, (id += 1).toString());
    return id;
}
```

But unfortunately when I execute this code I get `NaN`

Note: Here, `KEYS` is an object of `employeeId` key of value `employeeId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you will probably to change the first if statement as if you leave it like that it'd be like trying to retrieve a boolean from `localStorage`. As `KEYS.employeeId === null` will return a bool value.

Then, if it's convenient for you, you could just save the id as integers without needing to `parseInt()` and `toString()`.

```
function generateEmployeeId() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId) === null)
        localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, 0);

    let id = localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId);
    localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, ++id);
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your If statement condition is wrong.
Your are saying `localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId === null)` which is the equivalent to
`localStorage.getItem(false)`.
the return value of `localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId === null)` is `null` and `parseInt(null)` is `NaN`.
SO in order for your code to work just change the condition in the if statement to `localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId) === null`

```
    function generateEmployeeId() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId) === null)
        localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, 0);

    let id = localStorage.getItem(KEYS.employeeId);
    localStorage.setItem(KEYS.employeeId, ++id);
    return id;
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes, it works as expected but fully not. Can you explain why I am getting null from the second submission to the rest? For the first submission it return id 0